# Multiply two tf transforms converted to 4x4 matrices in python?

Tags: ros, python, rospy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
t = tf.getLatestCommonTime(l2, l4) 
mat1 = transRotToMat4x4(tf.lookupTransform(l2, l1, t))
mat2 = transRotToMat4x4(tf.lookupTransform(l4, l3, t))
mat3 = mat1 * mat3

trans,rot = Mat4x4ToPosQuat(mat3)

br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
br.sendTransform(
    trans,
    rot,
    t,
    "target",
    "source");
```

Does transformations.py have something like transRotToMat4x4 and the complementary function for going the other direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133331/multiply-two-tf-transforms-converted-to-4x4-matrices-in-python?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The transformations.py included in tf provided the functions for the solution, they create 4x4 numpy nd.arrays which are matrix multiplied with dot():

```
(trans1, rot1) = tf.lookupTransform(l2, l1, t)
trans1_mat = tf.transformations.translation_matrix(trans1)
rot1_mat   = tf.transformations.quaternion_matrix(rot1)
mat1 = numpy.dot(trans1_mat, rot1_mat)

(trans2, rot2) = tf.lookupTransform(l4, l3, t)
trans2_mat = tf.transformations.translation_matrix(trans2)
rot2_mat    = tf.transformations.quaternion_matrix(rot2)
mat2 = numpy.dot(trans2_mat, rot2_mat)

mat3 = numpy.dot(mat1, mat2)
trans3 = tf.transformations.translation_from_matrix(mat3)
rot3 = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_matrix(mat3)

br = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
br.sendTransform(
  trans3,
  rot3,
  t,
  "target",
  "source");
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3